# Error trying to update table through SQL loader

Tags: oracle, sql-update, sql-loader

I'm having issues trying to do an update on an Oracle table but keep getting an error and cant see anyother way of writing the script for what I need.

```
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Comment: Where does SQL\*Loader fit in? And why are you using a PL/SQl block for this?

Comment: Can you also show us the expected output?

Comment: @Tejash Just added what i would expect to see. Alex Pooles script help get rid of the error but now the values which should be updating are null.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
UPDATE REFERENCES F
     SET F.ID_VALUE = (
            SELECT STG.COM
            FROM STAGE_TABLE STG JOIN REFERENCES F1 
            ON STG.ITN = F1.ID_VALUE 
            WHERE F1.ID_TYPE = 'ITN'
             AND  F.JOB_ID = F1.JOB_ID
        )
WHERE F.ID_TYPE = 'COM';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of doing a correlated update, but then you reference your target table again. Every row you try to update will try to set its `id_value` to the result of the subquery:

```
SELECT STG.CODE
FROM STAGE_TABLE STG, REFERENCES F
WHERE STG.ITN = F.ID_VALUE
```

which will be many values, not the single one that is required - hence the error that you get. The `references` in that subquery is completely independent of the `references` in the outer update statement. (Incidentally, 'references' is a [keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Keywords.html#GUID-82EA000B-5661-41EB-AAF7-6BDDB4AB58EE) so might be a confusing name for an object.)

Take out the new `references` in the subquery:

```
UPDATE REFERENCES F
SET F.ID_VALUE = (
    SELECT STG.COM
    FROM STAGE_TABLE STG
    WHERE STG.ITN = F.ID_VALUE
)
WHERE F.REFERENCE_ID IN
(
    SELECT F1.REFERENCE_ID
    FROM STAGE_TABLE STG
    JOIN REFERENCES F2 ON F2.ID_VALUE = STG.ITN
    JOIN REFERENCES F1 ON F1.JOB_ID = F2.JOB_ID
    WHERE F1.ID_TYPE = 'COM'
    AND F2.ID_TYPE = 'ITN'
);
```

Your `IN` subquery looks a bit odd as well. Firstly you should be using ANSI join syntax; but it isn't entirely clear how they relate. I think what I've done is a straight translation, but not 100% it's what you really want.

You also don't need to use any PL/SQL here, you can run it as a plain SQL statement.

---

With your sample data, your filter subquery finds `reference_id` results 3 and 5. The matching references for those IDs are then updated. The `id_values` corresponding to those rows are 00018903 and 0005675, and there are no rows in `stage_table` matching those.

So you actually want something more like:

```
UPDATE REFERENCES F
SET F.ID_VALUE = (
    SELECT STG.COM
    FROM STAGE_TABLE STG
    JOIN REFERENCES F2 ON F2.ID_TYPE = 'ITN' AND F2.ID_VALUE = STG.ITN
    WHERE F2.JOB_ID = F.JOB_ID
)
WHERE ID_TYPE = 'COM'
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT null
    FROM STAGE_TABLE STG
    JOIN REFERENCES F2 ON F2.ID_TYPE = 'ITN' AND F2.ID_VALUE = STG.ITN
    WHERE F2.JOB_ID = F.JOB_ID
);

select * from references;

REFERENCE_ID     JOB_ID ID_ ID_VALUE 
------------ ---------- --- ---------
           1       1065 VAL 00601    
           2       1065 ITN NO000445 
           3       1065 COM 765775518
           4       1065 SEC SA897215 
           5       1066 COM 208784526
           6       1066 ITN N04009   
           7       1066 SEC SA1402877
           8       1066 VAL 006292
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32731e4fb3b0b39254b884047fcfa0f0)

The subquery in the `set` part finds the staging COM value matching an ITN in your reference table. The `exists` clause is basically the same, but prevents COM rows being updated if there is no match in the staging table - if it only contains a subset of the main table data, which seems a reasonable possibility. Without that any rows with matching data would be updated to null again.

Comment: Thanks for that, that query runs but it is updating the values to null instead of whats in the temp table. Also I edited some of the names to make it clear when asking but the table names/columns im using are different.

Comment: @random - your subquery is finding the wrong `reference_id` - see updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: I'm looking to update the COM in the references table though and not the ITN. The plan was to search for the ITN, find the connecting COM (as they have matching job_id) and from there update the value for COM. If this makes sense

Comment: that worked! that a million for all your help. much appreciated